# Solr - "group by" in 1.4

Tags: solr, group-by

I've looked for an answer all over the web but could not find an answer.

Let's say I have docs in solr which refer to persons. Each doc (person) has both "company name" and "date of birth" fields. How can I retrieve the date of birth of the oldest person in each company?
What I actually look for, is the option to perform a min function on the date of birth, and group by company.

I must mention I use solr 1.4.

Thank you in advance, Hadas

Comment: Your question might be duplicate. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413966/getting-maximum-value-of-field-in-solr)

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar feature called FieldCollapsing, but it only works on solr 3.3 and up.

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing